# uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I get this error on a .click() event in jQuery. I see it in Firebug. I use the latest version, 1.3.2 (min)
The click fires an $.ajax() request for a Form in my website. I asked google about this and all he knows is "%" or "[@]" as unrecognized expressions, nothing about the "#".

here is a bit of my code:

```
    $("form#buyForm #submitForm").live("click", function(e) {
        var errors = 0;

        var inputLastName_value = $("form#buyForm input#userLastName").val();
        if (inputLastName_value == "") {
         errors = 1;
         formErrorHandling("#userLastName");
         return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

This way I check all my inputs for errors, and then call formErrorHandling() who does some show/hide, stuff like that, nothing important.

I read that it might be from a selector of mine, but they all seem to be just fine.

Anybody else had the same problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are nesting `#ids` in your selectors? An element id should be unique on the page, so nesting them or specifying them with `form` or `input` seems a little odd.

Comment: What I mean is, why use `form#buyForm #submitForm` when you can just say `#submitForm` etc

Comment: dcneiner, yes, id's should be and are unique. The reason I use tag name before selector, at least from what I've read, is speed. So jQuery uses the getElementByTagName and knows exactly what to search, instead of looking at all id's from my page.

Comment: I'm not using it in all my code, as you can see, but mainly in forms, inputs, and stuff like that, not with div, p, etc. It's just the way I used to, with.

Comment: This is an old conversation but I will use `#parent #child` in a selector when I want it to work on one page but not another and I know the JS file is shared between them and there is a `#child` on each page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can see the exception seems to be somehow triggered by the `jScrollPane` plugin you are using.

Try replacing the script you include (v1.2.3 which is as old as from Dec 2008) with a newer version directly from the trunk. Which includes many improvements over v.1.2.3 and fixes the exception for me [jScrollPane.js](http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/source/browse/trunk/demo/scripts/jScrollPane.js) ([jScrollPane.min.js](http://pastebin.com/pastebin.php?dl=m71c2385d) minified version of  r87 jScrollPane minified with YUICompressor)

---

removed old answer stuff no longer needed

Comment: jitter, I don't know where the exception occur, interesting fact is that this happens only with one of my form's (I have two forms on my website, both using the same formErrorHandling() function and following the same code pattern) I posted the JS containing this part of form handling here: http://artdevmedia.net/gds/test.js note: the main function wich includes the form related ones is being called after an ajax request success.

Comment: check expanded answer: especially the part about `$("#"+id)` and `elements:textarea`

Comment: Hi jitter thank you for your time. I tested over and over again and I think that the error might not be caused by my forms or by the error handling function. That's one. Two, it doesn't happen all the time. Anyway, if you have time, take a look here: artdevmedia.net/gds -- here's what I found: If you click on "BUY ALBUM" and then go on with form completing, etc, there's no exception. Now, click on "VIDEO" and then click on X to close video. Sometimes that's the moment when exception throws, other times, the exception throws after closing Video and going back to BUY ALBUM form and submiting it

Comment: What I mean is that the cause of the exception, after all, is more likely that VIDEO closing link, and I can't seem to know what's wrong with it. Note that the link is created dinamically with js and appended to div. May that be the cause? Am I doing something wrong there? You can look at the hole javascript file if you want and have time. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I fixed the bug you mentioned, the one with elements:textarea and rewrote my selectors.

Comment: oh!!! thanks so much jitter, that worked! no more exception! great! :) isn't there a minified version of the new jScrollPane? I can't seem to find it. 43K is quite big. Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: Added minified version of it (~8kb). Minified with YUICompressor (the one which jQuery itself uses)

Comment: Thanks jitter. I just had the same issue now, but it was related to me incorrectly targeting the navigation links for jQuery ScrollTo plugin which caused the error.

Answer (score 3):

In some browsers id might be empty and JQuery chokes on "#" as a selector.

Comment: btw, I'm not sure what conditions cause the actual error, but i was running into the same problem with the jqGrid plugin. The plugin code seemed to cause jquery to choke just about everywhere when there was no id in the component turned into a jqGrid. I solved the problem by assigning a random selector to the element.

    table.attr("id","table" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100000));

Answer (score 1):

Sept 2011

changed from

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#'+id).creatorCall( {init:param} ) ;
} );
```

to

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $(this).creatorCall( {init:param} ) ;
} );
```

and cured that self same `uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` message

Answer (score 0):

what does the formErrorHandling function look like? Is it expecting a selector or a jQuery object?

perhaps what you need is to call it like

```
formErrorHandling($("#userLastName"));
```

Comment: hi Victor, the formErrorHandling function looks like this: function formErrorHandling(id, filter) { id=id.replace("#",""); ... } afterwards I do a switch(id) and then show the right message error for that id. (and if it has filter, show a specific message)

Comment: Adrian, If you are removing the "#", why do you bother setting it when you execute the function?

Comment: Well, you're right, I could just call formErroHandling("userLastName") without #, and not removing it in function. I left it there, for a better tracking of my code. At least, for me, that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old issue and there's newer version jScrollPane but as I needed to use current one for due to a legacy issues here's the fix. If you'll use [jScrollPane.js](http://code.google.com/p/jscrollpane/source/browse/trunk/demo/scripts/jScrollPane.js) from the answer above you need to change the code in line 534:

change:

```
    if (h && h.substr(0, 1) == '#' && h.length > 1) {
```

to

```
    if (h && h!='#' && h.substr(0, 1) == '#' && h.length > 1) {
```

Whole chunk of the code responsible for document clicks with the fix:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e){
    $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.is('a')) {
        var h = $target.attr('href');
        if (h && h!='#' && h.substr(0, 1) == '#' && h.length > 1) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                scrollTo(h, !settings.animateToInternalLinks);
            }, $.browser.safari ? 100 : 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Basically the `scrollTo` function will be ignored if link's `href` equals `#`

Cheers

G.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me seemed to be caused by having one too many # in the selector.

For example:

```
$('##id_name')
```

should have been...

```
$('#id_name')
```