# TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have read threads on this topic on SO, but not able to get the required o/p. They said this problem arises because some js files are being included multiple times. But I tried removing the multiple files one-by-one, but still getting the `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` Error. Where I'm including multiple js files? Can someone please point it out. Thanks.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js" %}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/inettuts.js" %}" ></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/dashboard.js" %}" ></script>
```

The errors that I get are :-

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #intro,
    ...nction(e){var t,n="",r=0,i=e.nodeType;if(i){if(1===i||9===i||11===i){if("string"...    
jquery.min.js (line 4)

TypeError: t.widget.extend is not a function
    ..."drag",e,s)===!1)return this._mouseUp({}),!1;this.position=s.position}return thi...
   jquery-ui.min.js (line 5)
```

Comment: Why are you including so many jquery-libs?

Comment: Not a good practice..Multiple jquery libraries will lead to disaster..

Comment: I've removed the multiple js files, but still getting some new error. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You still got a personalized one there. Not sure what that one means.

Comment: Note for MVC5 user: The error will occur when u try to insert more than 1 Jquery lib OR 1 version of jquery but more than 1 time, example first time from Bundle and another time from manual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple of jQuery libraries being loaded on the same page (different versions of the same thing), which is wrong, unless you really need to keep old plugins working that depend on previous versions. In this specific case you would need to work out the conflicts.

That's all you need:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/bootstrap.js" %}" ></script>
<!-- Not so sure what is this, but certainly it's another jQuery UI library being loaded on top of the other one -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js" %}" ></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/inettuts.js" %}" ></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "dashboard/js/dashboard.js" %}" ></script>
```

Look here for the CSS stylesheet (play with the theme): http://jqueryui.com/

The jQuery UI Dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

**UPDATE**

After our chat on the comments, I've found out that you're using a plugin called `inettuts` which is based on really old versions of jQuery and jQuery UI libraries (1.2.x).
Also, it uses a customized version of the jQuery UI which doesn't includes the `dialog` widget, hence the first error message.

You can try to adapt the plugin to work with newer versions (following the comments on its own website) or work out the conflicts and use two libraries on the same page.

It's up to you now.

Comment: I tried removing the 1.9.1 version(3rd line), ie `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`, but it still gives me the same error. Moreover jQuery UI lib is present. See 4th line.

Comment: Remove all the other jQuery versions you're adding to the page and leave just the ones I'm pointing out in the answer.

Comment: Now it Gives me 2 errors. `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #intro,` in `jQuery.min.js` and `TypeError: t.widget.extend is not a function` in `jquery-ui.min.js (line 5)`.

Comment: The earlier error `TypeError: $(…).dialog is not a function Error` has been removed, but gets 2 new errors.

Comment: Please see the updated question to refer what I did.

Comment: You still have a personalized one there. Not sure what that one means.

Comment: I removed that one too. But I still gets the first error, ie `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #intro,
 

...nction(e){var t,n="",r=0,i=e.nodeType;if(i){if(1===i||9===i||11===i){if("string"...`

Comment: Do you have a live URL where I can see the page running?

Comment: Sorry. I'm running it locally.

Comment: jquery.min.js file Line 4.

Comment: It seems to be a really old issue. I mean, with really old jQuery libraries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775786/uncaught-exception-syntax-error-unrecognized-expression

Comment: Edit your question and include the whole page `<head>`, please. Also, if it's possible, any other `<script>` code along the page.

Comment: A check you can do is to inspect the page on the Developer Tools (F12) and look for the sources being loaded. You'll be able to see every JS file that's being added to the page.

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/). So using their libraries for creating and dragging widgets, hence using their js library files(old files). And for adding modal form, I'm using different js libraries(new files). So, when I remove the js file(which you were not sure of) the dragging facility of the widgets goes off. So I think I need to add the old and new js files both.
You can inquire more if you didnt understood. Thanks

Comment: The modal dialog comes as default on any jQuery UI library version, but on that personalized library it's not present. You'll need to download both the regular jQuery and the UI libraries that make this inettuts work, making sure you enable the dialog widget for the UI.

Comment: Bloody hell. The inettuts on the page you sent me is using jQuery 1.2.x, which is pre-historic and will cause you lots of headaches. Are you sure you can't find a more up-to-date inettuts somewhere?

Comment: Besides, what this "tool" does you can find on the regular jQuery UI widgets pack. Draggable, Sortable, Collapsible...

Comment: Check this comment on the inettuts page: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/#comment-777465714

Comment: Yaa I know they use ancient version of jquery. But I was being lazy to write my own code. Will now gonna write it from scratch. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at in the generated source code, then find out all the references to jquery, then check out that there is only one reference to jquery and one to jquery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the js libraries that you are referencing in jsp/html in corresponding folder. Mostly it would be WebContent folder or the path you specify in jsp. For me it was in /resources/scripts folder. Once I added the libraries there